# Linux SIP Client just to get incoming number

Tags: linux, console, sip

I'm looking for a SIP client based on linux (console only, debian if possible) for one simple goal : To let my CRM app know what is the incoming call number.

There is no need to use voice, autoresponder, etc., I just need to get the incoming call number send somewhere (fill a file with the number, add a row in a sql database, a curl request to my CRM or anything else like that)

Do you know a SIP client that can let me do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your intent to receive a SIP INVITE and identify the calling number using this? Because you mentioned you don't need Voice or anything else, a simple SIPP kind of test tool should be fine.

Or do you want to test it over the mobile Network and hence want to use a VoIP Client. or just use the freeware of Xlite etc from either a desktop or mobile device.